# Showing $\displaystyle\lim_{z\rightarrow ^{-}1}\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 0}z^{2^n}$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have been trying to bound this below, as the TA suggested, by some taylor series of a function I know diverges at $x=1$, like $\log(\frac{1}{1-x})$ taylor expanded around zero:

$$-\log(1-x)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+...$$

Which obviously doesn't work for $x<1$. Any tips? I am also curious to see some different ways of proving this.

Comment: the extended https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem works also when $\lim_{K \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^K c_k = +\infty$.

Comment: Is that $z$ supposed to be $r$, or is it something else?

Comment: Yes sorry editing

Comment: If we choose $z$ real positive, and $z^{2^n}\ge 1/2$, then the sum up to $n$ is $\ge \lfloor n/2\rfloor$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas why is this?

Comment: exactly for the reason I wrote below, because you can easily bound below $f(r)$ when all the coefs are $\ge 0$

Comment: Because there are $n$ terms (actually $n+1$, I thought it started at $n=1$), and each is $\ge 1/2$.

Comment: Curiously the alternating sum $\sum_n (-1)^n z^{2^n}$, 
which might be expected to approach $1/2$ as $z \to 1$ from below, 
also doesn't converge, though that's more delicate; see for instance
http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/sol8.html .

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies In fact $\lim_{r\to1^-}f(re^{it})$ does not exist for _any_ $t$. If a "lacunary series" has a radial limit at a boundary point then the series actually converges at that point, and it's clear that this series does not converge at any point of the boundary.

Comment: Yes, there's a few "soft" ways of seeing and generalizing the result; still this particular series has some neat special features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if $c_k \ge 0$ and $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^k$ converges for $|z|< 1$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k $ diverges, then $$\lim_{ r \to 1^-} f(r) = +\infty$$

simply write $$f_K(z) = \sum_{k=0}^K c_k z^k$$
then for every $K$ and $r \in [0,1[$ : $$f(r) \ge f_K(r)$$ hence for every $K$ :

$$\lim_{ r \to 1^-} f(r) \ge \lim_{ r \to 1^-} f_K(r) = \sum_{k=0}^K c_k$$

proving that $\lim_{ r \to 1^-} f(r)$ is unbounded.

Comment: +1 to the otherwise unsung hero to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to show that the limit does not exist that's more or less obvious: $\sum z^{2^n}>\sum_{n=1}^Nz^{2^n}$, so the limit is larger than $N$ for every $N$.

But you *can* bound it below by that logarithm. Possibly interesting, also  it tells you how fast the function blows up. Note that $$\sum_{j=2^{n-1}+1}^{2^n}\frac{z^j}{j}\le z^{2^{n-1}}\sum_{j=2^{n-1}+1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=z^{2^{n-1}}\quad(0<z<1).$$

Comment: your bound doesn't say yet if $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}$ has a pole or an essential singularity (or a branch point ?) at $z=1$, possibly useful for answering the OP in the case $z \to 1$ (not only $z \to 1^-$)

Comment: @user1952009 It's not defined anywhere outside the disk, so it can't possibly have a pole or essentially singularity or branch point! None of the above.

Comment: and I think, given the slow growth rate of $\sum_n z^{2^n}$ as $z \to 1^-$ that $z=1$ cannot be a pole, and is probably a branch point (if we can analytically continuate the function outside of $|z| < 1$)

Comment: @user1952009 The function has no analytic continuation. It is extremely nasty near every boundary point.

Comment: ok, I knew this was possible but I was not sure. tks

Comment: @user1952009 there is a dense set of points on the boundary of the unit disk, which you can see by looking at the points $e^{i\frac{a}{b}\pi}$. The above was all part of a proof that there is no analytic continuation for the function defined by this power series

Comment: @qbert : now I remember, I indeed proved it in an other question :D considering the set of points $\exp(2 i\pi \frac{a}{2^b} )$ which is dense in the unit circle

Comment: @user1952009 that way is even better, an uncountable number of dense points haha

Comment: @qbert :  countably infinite number of poles dense in the unit circle, i.e. no open $\{|z-e^{i \theta} | < r\} \cap \{z \le 1 \}$ where $f(z)$ is holomorphic, and no way for continuating $f(z)$ out of the open unit disk

Comment: @user1952009 Not that it matters, but isn't your example uncountable, since every real has a binary expansion?

Comment: @qbert : I meant $a,b \in \mathbb{N}^2$

Comment: @user1952009 ah ok yes, agreed

Comment: @user1952009 You can't call them poles! First, because they're not poles, and second because $f$ does _not_ tend to infinity at those points! In fact there exists a sequence $(z_n)$ with $|z_n|<1$ and $z_n\to1$ such that $f(z_n)$ is dense in the plane. (And either every or almost every boundary point is just as bad; the points $e^{2\pi i/2^n}$ are just the ones where it's most obvious...)

Comment: I should have said rays $r e^{2 i \pi a / 2^b}, r \in [0,1[$ where $f(r e^{2 i \pi a / 2^b}) \to +\infty$ as $r \to 1^-$. but how do you get that $f(z) \not \to +\infty$  for other paths  $z \to e^{it}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 See the new Answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2):

From [Cauchy's Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{2^n}&\ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}\\\\
&=-\log(1-z) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find from $(1)$ that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to 1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{2^n}&\ge -\lim_{z\to 1^-}\log(1-z)\\\\
&=\infty
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Sorry, isn't the first fact false for $z<1$?

Comment: @qbert Why do you believe that?   Look at the development in the cited article.  -Mark

Comment: i guess because you are taking higher powers of a thing smaller than 1 on the left side? edit: I think I actually misread the article, thinking now

Comment: The right-hand side series has summand $\frac{z^n}{n}$, not $z^n$.

Comment: yes ok I see now, I had never seen this, thank you! It looks like it doesn't work for complex $z$, is that true? if so, what goes wrong?

Comment: Note that $$\sum_{n=1}^{2^N-1}f(n)\le \sum_{n=1}^N 2^nf(2^n)$$ when $f(n)$ is a non-negative, non-increasing sequence of real numbers.

Comment: If we have a complex summand, then one can certainly state $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{2^n-1}f(n)\right|\le \sum_{n=1}^{2^n-1}\left| f(n) \right|\le \sum_{n=1}^N 2^n|f(2^n)|$$The proof follows for the case herein since $- \lim_{|z|\to 1^-}\log(1-|z|)=\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

What about the complex case? Define $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}\quad(|z|<1).$$

There have been several comments about how bad $f$ is at the boundary, but in fact it's worse than any of the commenters  seem to realize.

First, there does not exist a boundary point $e^{it}$ such that $\lim_{r\to 1^-}f(re^{it})$ exists. This follows from a "tauberian theorem" about "lacunary series", which shows that if $f$ has a radial limit at a given boundary point then the series itself converges at that point. Our series certainly converges  at no point of the boundary, hence it has a radial limit at no boundary point. (If I find a reference for that tauberian theorem I'll insert it here.)

Things are much worse than that. For example, although $f$ tends to infinity as you approach various boundary points radially, it does worse than that as you approach a boundary point in an arbitrary way from inside the disk.

In fact, for every $t$ there exists a sequence $(z_n)$ with $|z_n|<1$ and $z_n\to e^{it}$ such that the sequence $f(z_n)$ is dense in the plane!
We can say a little about why that's so.

For each $t\in \Bbb R$ let $S_t$ be the interior of the convex hull of $\{e^{it}\}\cup\{|z|<1/2\}$. The region $S_t$ is a "Stolz angle", or "nontangential approach region" - draw a picture to understand why approaching $e^{it}$ from within $S_t$ is known as "nontangential convergence".

Say $f$ has a nontangential limit at $e^{it}$ if $$\lim_{S_t\ni z\to e^{it}}f(z)$$exists. Say $f$ is nontangentially dense at $e^{it}$ if $f(S_t)$ is dense in the plane.

**Plessner's Theorem** If $g$ is holomorphic in the unit disc then for almost every $t$, either $g$ has a nontangential limit at $e^{it}$ or $g$ is nontangentially dense at $e^{it}$.

I haven't found an online reference for that. It's in various books, for example Garnett *Bounded Analytic Functions*, I think in Duren *Theory of $H^p$ Spaces*, various other books on Hardy spaces.

Now our function $f$ has a radial limit at no boundary point, hence a nontangential limit at no boundary point, so Plessaner says that $f$ is nontangentially dense at almost every boundary point. It follows easily from this that for *every* $t$ there exists $z_n\to e^{it}$ such that $f(z_n)$ is dense (note that $z_n$ tends to $e^{it}$, but not nontangentially).

Answer (score 1):

If we choose $z$ real positive, and $z^{2^n}\ge 1/2$, then $z^{2^k}\ge 1/2$ for all $k\le n$. So taking account of the fact that the first term is $1$, our partial sum up to $n$ is $\gt n/2$, and so goes to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

To make sure that $z^{2^n}\ge 1/2$, it is enough to choose $z\gt \exp(-\ln(2)/2^n)$. This is less than $1$.

Comment: (you also have to say that $\sum_{m > n} r^{2^m}$ is non-negative : for bounding below you use the fact that all the coefs are non-negative)

Comment: I didn't say there was any problem, just that your argument is $f(r) \ge \sum_{k \le n} r^{2^k}$ which is $\ge n/2$ when $r \to 1^-$, i.e. the same as mine

Comment: there is a huge difference between the limit does not exist and the limit is $+ \infty$. in many settings, a limit $+\infty$ can be considered convergent.

Comment: @user1952009: Our arguments are indeed structurally similar, with yours substantially more general.

Comment: @user1952009: Yes, there is a difference. Because of the tags and OP's work (and despite the $z$) I assumed the setting was real variables.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm not sure I follow what changes if $z$ is complex, can't we just replace your real z with $|z|$?

Comment: André, what I meant since the beginning is that you need to write in your answer that $\lim_{r \to 1^-} \sum_{m=0}^\infty r^{2^m} \ge\lim_{r \to 1^-} \sum_{m=0}^n r^{2^m}$  (@qbert)

Comment: @qbert: We cannot, because of possible cancellations.

Comment: even if it is obvious, it is the key argument : we can easily bound below because every terms are $\ge 0$