# Convergence of $f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, formal-power-series

If we define $f(x)= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^{2^m} = \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{n} x^{2^m}$.

It's easy to see that $|{f(x)}|$ converge in the interval $(-1,1)$. (We can easily born it with the geometric series)

Supose I want to look at the limit :
$$\lim_{x\to1^-}|f(x)|$$
**How could a prove that the limit  diverge ?**

I would like to evaluate the limit as x approach $1^-$ first and then use the limite as  n tend to infinity like:
$$ \lim_{x\to1^-}\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x)| =  \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to1^-}|f_n(x)| $$

but my function is not continuous at x = 1. I also dont find any function that could born $f(x)$ ( that we know diverge at 1 and is smaller then $f(x)$ on the interval $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing $\displaystyle\lim_{z\rightarrow ^{-}1}\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 0}z^{2^n}$ does not exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788426/showing-displaystyle-lim-z-rightarrow-1-displaystyle-sum-n-geq-0z2n); see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem